# Handling Microservice Requests with Responses

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, microservices

What kind of design patterns would one use, if they were implementing the following functionality using microservice architecture?

There's an **API Gateway** and some sort of **user management** service. The API Gateway translates REST API (HTTP) calls into calls onto the appopriate message bus.

The user sends a GET request, and provides user ID and wants to retrieve the information associated with that user (e.g., username, email, ...). I can see how that would naturally translate to the API Gateway publishing a message onto a MQ such as `{"type": "GET_USER_INFO", "uid":xxxx}`.

How would the user management send the response back to the the API Gateway for it to send the request back to the user?

I'm implementing this using Python/Flask/Gunicorn/Pika (RabbitMQ) so any further implementation tips etc would be incredibl helpful.

Comment: Client requests are typically handled synchronously, using RPCs rather than events. Events are facts about something that happened, and don't usually represent questions that need to be answered by other events. (See also: Events vs Commands). Gateways also don't generally subscribe to events, specific services do. If you do need services to send and receive data bidirectionally with events, you need both services to listen for the other one's event.

Comment: Doesn't using an RPC more strongly couple the gateway to each individual request each type of microservice can handle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally queries are performed synchronously via direct http calls rather than a message bus, as when a client requests some information it needs a response (the requested data or an error) straight away.

If you perform queries via your message bus, you have no guarantee when you'll get a response, so clients will be left hanging indefinitely. You also have the issue that you've discovered where it's hard to tie a query request to a response.

In theory you could implement a Saga pattern to keep track of the query transaction, but you'll still face the issue of clients hanging indefinitely. Additionally this request/response mapping isn't something you'd want to do in an API gateway as it'll seriously bloat it's responsibilities.

As for your worry that synchronous calls will tightly couple your gateway to each individual microservice, you should take a look at client-side or server-side discovery utilising a service registry. Only the service registry will know the physical addresses of your services so it's easy to configure and keep up to date.

If you don't need a response within a defined timeframe, you could look at an event-based pattern, i.e. you send a `CreateUser` command that gets handled by your `UserService`, and at some point later your `UserService` will publish a `UserCreated` event with details about the newly created user. However you'd need to store these user details where you intend to use them to avoid having to query the `UserService` synchronously at a later date anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the REST gateway needs to handle security, directly accessing user details from the store of that data (DB, Keycloak, OKTA, etc) makes sense.  Don't build yet another service to access that information.

If there's a need/desire to decouple from the implementation that stores that data, then a lightweight library that maps to the backend calls can do the job.

...Extending to consider other types of data where we would break them into a separate service.  Answering the question "how to handle requests with replies over a message bus" - here are two key patterns that can be used:

1. Request/Reply over the messaging solution.  Use a "reply-to" property on the message (some messaging middelware have this built-in) that tells consumers of the message where to send a reply.  Then the requestor can either have a permanent queue for all its replies, or it can create a temporary queue for the reply.
2. Event-based pattern.  The processor fires an event to a permanent broadcast desintation (topic) on completion of the processing, and the requestor listens for those events.

In either case, having a unique identifier for the request (e.g. Correlation ID) is ideal.

Comment: Sure, this was just the first example that came to mind. What about similar data that isn't user data?